# Get back empty nodejs + firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Guys I need some help with a get return with node and firebase.

I get an empty array.

but in console.log inside foreach prints correct

[{cnpj: '03052164798-000179', Address: 'Av Duke of Caxias 99999', Name: 'Testing', Tel: '999999999'}]

```
getEmpresas() {
    let empresas = []

    firebase.firestore().collection('empresa').get().then(snapshot => {

      snapshot.docs.forEach(empresa => {

        empresas.push(empresa.data())
        console.log(empresas)
      });

    })
    return empresas
```

Comment: Did you tried with a `return` inside your `.then()`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a question about async. You're not getting the data you expect in the `return` because that fires before the async request is made. You'd need something like:

```
const getEmpresas = async () => {
  let empresas = []

  const snapshot = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('empresa')
    .get();

  snapshot.docs.forEach((empresa) => {
    empresas.push(empresa.data());
  });

  return empresas;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As imjared said in his answer, the function returns before `.get()` gets executed because it is an asynchronous function

You will need to return the chain of firebase functions which will return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
getEmpresas() {
  return firebase.firestore().collection('empresa').get().then(snapshot => (
    snapshot.docs.map(({ data }) => data())
  ))
}
```

Then to access the returned Promise use `.then()` on the Promise or `await` inside an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
getEmpresas.then(empresas => console.log(empresas))
```

Or inside an async function

```
const main = async () => {
  const empresas = await getEmpresas()
  console.log(empresas)
}

main()
```

Comment: I think you'll need an additional `return` in the inner callback in the first snippet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Wrapping an arrow function with `()` is acting just like implicit return, its there only for readability

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure that works when you have `{}` around the function body? In my quick test declaring `var test = () => "yes"` and then calling `test()` returns `"yes"`. But with `var test = () => { "yes" }`, calling `test()` returns `undefined`. I just checked and MDN seems to confirm that the test results I see are expected: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax, but I now notice you're using `()` and not `{}`.